# how can I get the date and time from access.log first field (squid)?

Tags: logs, squid

this is a line from access.log file which log the access Info of Squid:

```
1286536351.746  41762 192.168.0.227 TCP_MISS/200 5340945 GET http://v15.lscache3.c.youtube.com/videoplayback? - DIRECT/122.160.120.150 video/x-flv
```

as we know the first column `1286536351.746` is representing the time stamp how can I get the date and the time from this field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/97214-unix-timestamp-readable-date.html).

```
me@host:~$ date -d @1286536351.746
Fri Oct  8 11:12:31 UTC 2010
```